# Select all check boxes in GridView when clicking asp:linkbutton in jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I want to select all checkboxes that are in gridview using asp:linkbutton. Here is what I have tried not sure about this line thou - `$(this("id*='chkGrid']").attr('checked', true));`

```
$('.SelectAll').click(SelectAll);

function SelectAll() {
    $('#gvw tr').each(function () {
        $(this("id*='chkGrid']").attr('checked', true));
    });
}
```

And this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvw" BorderColor="black" RowStyle-BorderColor="LightGray" BorderWidth="1" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-CssClass="headerStyle"
     HeaderStyle-BackColor="LightGray" OnRowCommand="gvw_RowCommand" Height="35px" AllowSorting="true" OnSorting="gvw_Sorting"
     GridLines="Both" DataKeyNames="TicketID" Width="98%" AutoGenerateColumns="false" EmptyDataText="No data found." CellPadding="2" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-BackColor="LightBlue" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="false">
            <ItemTemplate>&nbsp;&nbsp;</ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

```
    </Columns> 
</asp:GridView>

<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkSelectAll" runat="server" CssClass="SelectAll" OnClientClick="SelectAll();" >Select All</asp:LinkButton>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about something like

```
$('#gvw').find('input:checkbox').prop('checked', true);
```

As of jQuery 1.6 you should use `prop` rather than `attr` for setting checkbox states as `attr` has been deprecated:  http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: What does the final HTML with the table and checkbox columns look like?  Can you post a jsfiddle with the resulting HTML?

Comment: Sure! Here it is:                                                   <div >                                                                  <div>                                                            <table>                                                            <tbody>                                                                    <tr>                                                             <tr>                                                                  <td>                                                                   <input checkbox goes here /> ...

Comment: I got the solution $('.gvw tr').each(function () {

            $('.Checkbox input:checkbox').prop('checked', true); This works perfect !!!